# How to control format options of an exported animation?

Tags: export, version-9, animation

My woes with Mathematica animations exported in SWF-format continue. The goal is to Export an animation in SWF-format, and also make it scalable, so that when I embed it into a slide set (produced by LaTeX) in PDF-format, the animation will resize when I zoom in/out. I have asked a [related question on TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/148430/9446), where a solution via converting the animation into an MP4-file was suggested. That solution works, but lossy compression (or something) makes the end result look passable but not nearly as good as the same animation in a Mathematica notebook.

Following the further discussion in TeX.SE I looked at the header of the generated SWF-file with a text editor (NotePad). Indeed, there reads `scaleMode -      noScale`. So time to study Mathematica's help files. Promising sounding options are listed in `ref/format/SWF`. Most notably *Scalable* and *ControlAppearance* (kind of pointless to have those unclickable control buttons in the end product). So let's try...

```
roll[u_] := Show[
  {ParametricPlot[{Cos[t] + u, Sin[t] + 1}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
    AspectRatio -> Automatic, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
    Ticks -> {{0, 2 Pi, 4 Pi, 6 Pi}, {}}],
   ParametricPlot[{u, 1} - t {Sin[u], Cos[u]}, {t, 0, 1}],
   ParametricPlot[{t - Sin[t], 1 - Cos[t]}, {t, -0.6, u}],
   Graphics[{PointSize[0.02], Point[{u - Sin[u], 1 - Cos[u]}]}]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1.2, 20}, {-0.2, 4.2}}, Axes -> True]

sykloidi = Animate[roll[u], {u, 0, 20}]

Export["Analyysi I/2013/kalvot12-13/sykloidi.swf", sykloidi, 
 AnimationDuration -> 6, FrameRate -> 8, Scalable -> True, 
 ControlAppearance -> None]
```

Nope. No change. The .swf still does not scale. In the header of the SWF-file it still reads `scaleMode -      noScale`, and the control buttons didn't disappear either.

> Did I use wrong syntax for `Export` in the above snippet? What's the right way of doing this?

Comment: Try `"Scalable" -> True` instead!

Comment: Oh dear! @belisarius is right! How did I miss that <insert blushing emoticon>? It zooms just right, too! Would you like to write that as an answer, please? This is the first time I have ever seen a Mathematica-option needing quotation marks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know why, but many options require the Option Name enclosed in quotation marks.
In this case:

```
"Scalable" -> True
```

Usually the docs are clear enough (if you are mostly awake and pay attention):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: My guess is that they want to reduce namespace pollution, as strings aren't symbols, but the usage pattern seems a bit haphazard.